# Petrel & Ocean licensing

Tags: licensing, ocean, petrel

I am trying to understand how licensing works for Petrel & Ocean. If a company needs to develop its own custom plugins/modules, does it need to buy explicit Ocean SDK license or just with Petrel runtime license, they can do development? I do understand that Ocean SDK brings along with it help CHMs, few samples plus VS project wizards for Ocean but in my understanding, that's something which is not mandatorily 'needed' to do plugin development as SLB Ocean assemblies are part of Petrel installation. So if one has only Petrel runtime license, can they legally do development, deployment, runtime etc for their plugin?

Or is it that Petrel runtime license cost inherently contains the cost of Ocean SDK license as well? If that's the case, then for a plugin development company to do full plugin lifecycle (development, deployment, testing), can they only buy Ocean SDK license and still be able to do it all without core Petrel license? Assuming tainting of projects is not an issue....

Thanks,
M

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1):

To develop plugins for Petrel you need to use the Ocean public APIs, marketed as Ocean Development Framework. A proper Ocean Framework license is needed. You can use the developer's area of the Ocean Store to request your package and agreement, visit http://www.ocean.slb.com and we will happily attend to your request.

Thanks for reaching out.